# (VueJS) vue-router match multiple paths

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I am using vue-router, and am looking to match two very distinct paths.  Is there some kind of array notation I can use?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can use an alias in the routes:

```
routes: [
  { path: '/foo', component: Foo, alias: '/bar'}
]
```

There are some nice examples here:

https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/dev/examples/route-alias/app.js

Answer (score 9):

Best way to achive this is :

```
{
    path: '/internalplatforms',
    alias: ['/a_internalplatforms', '/b_internalplatforms'],
    name: 'ImportantPlatform',
    component: ImportantPlatform
}
```

By aliasing, you can call internalplatforms or a_internalplatforms or b_internalplatforms and it will show that same component.